# Is google chart geochart free of use?

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization, geo

I'm developing an android app that uses google charts geochart.
Is the mapsApiKey for free? 
My app will not be free.

thanks

For now I use a mapsApiKey that I copied from an example:

```
    google.charts.load(versionFirstWithKey, {
      'packages': ['geochart'],
      'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
    });
```

Can I use this mapsApiKey to get rid of the warning ?

Comment: _Can I use this mapsApiKey to get rid of the warning ?_ What warning?

Comment: Yes you need your own api key! Look at the code in this example 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Answer (score 0):

No. Maps API is not for free.

> Get API Key
>
> To use the Maps JavaScript API, you must get an API key
>   which you can then add to your mobile app, website, or web server. 
>   The API key is used to track API requests associated with your project
>   for usage and billing. To learn more about API keys, see the API Key
>   Best Practices and the FAQs.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 0):

Google Charts itself is FREE.

The mapsApiKey that you are referring to is an API key for the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), You will need to create a billing account to get your own, and you will be provided with a free trial period. It is your choice if you decide to upgrade it or not.